# I dont want my batch program to terminate after it calls "spl stop"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scope

I have my batch script below:-

```
@echo off
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (test.properties) DO (
    IF "%%A"=="PORT" set PORT=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="SPLEBASE" set SPLEBASE=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="SPLOUTPUT" set SPLOUTPUT=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="SPLENVIRON" set SPLENVIRON=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="JAVA_HOME" set JAVA_HOME=%%B  
    IF "%%A"=="jarsource" set jarsource=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="jartarget" set jartarget=%%B
    )
echo.
echo The environment properties are as follows :-
echo.
echo port number is %PORT%
echo environment path is %SPLEBASE%
echo environment output location is %SPLOUTPUT%
echo environment name is %SPLENVIRON%
echo java home is %JAVA_HOME%
echo cm jar source location is %jarsource%
echo cm jar target location is %jartarget%
echo.
echo on
cd %SPLEBASE%/bin
spl stop
echo off
:loop
netstat -n -o -a | findstr ":6500" 
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (@echo "listening") ELSE goto exitloop
goto loop
:exitloop
echo server has been stopped
```

The problem is that after It executes spl stop, it exits from my current batch program and does not go into the coming loop at all. spl.cmd is a file that calls a vb script which executes and exits hence terminating my current batch program. I don't want my batch program to terminate. Please suggest something so that my batch proceeds to the loop after running spl stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `CALL` command:

```
call spl stop
```